# Search and replace using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that has hundreds of lines and each line has a set of characters with the delimiter ~ like below.

```
T01~T02~T03~T04~T05~T06~T07~T08~T09~T10~T11~~T13
.
.
.
.
```

I need to remove T02,T11 and T12 using awk. If you see the above string the T12 is null but still i need to empty that position and my output should look like :

```
T01~T03~T04~T05~T06~T07~T08~T09~T13
```

I have tried the following awk command

```
awk -F~ '{$2=$11=$12="";print $0}'
```

but it's giving the output like

```
T01 T02 T03 T04 T05 T06 T07 T08 T09 T10 T11  T13
```

Can anyone please let me know if I missed anything..

Comment: `cut -d~ -f 1,3-9,13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `OFS`, and you can change `print $0` to `1`

```
awk -F~ '{$2=$11=$12=""} gsub(/~+/,"~")' OFS="~"
T01~T03~T04~T05~T06~T07~T08~T09~T10~T13
```

Comment: Not enought. He wants to get rid of separators between those removed fields. Try with `gsub()`, like: `gsub(/~+/, "~")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut`:

```
$ echo "T01~T02~T03~T04~T05~T06~T07~T08~T09~T10~T11~~T13" | cut -d~ -f1,3-10,13
T01~T03~T04~T05~T06~T07~T08~T09~T10~T13
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the output field separator:

```
awk  -F~ '{$2=$11=$12="";print $0}' OFS="~"
```

Comment: This leaves several separators between those fields removed.